# Java: логарифм с произвольным основанием

Tags: java

Я знаю, что в языке Java есть функция `Math.log(a)`, которая вычисляет логарифм с основанием `e`. Есть `Math.log10(a)` для основания 10. Но как средствами Java вычислить логарифм с другим основанием, например, log 50 base 2?

Comment: Что такое решение логарифма? Может быть вычисление?

Comment: Что подразумевается под "решением логарифма"? Если имелось ввиду вычисление логарифма, то Вы логарифм по любому основанию можете представить через натуральные логарифмы(вычисление которых в Math, очевидно, присутствует)

Comment: Я так понимаю, вам просто нужно узнать, какая есть встроенная функция вычисления логарифма?

Comment: есть Math.log(), но там что то не понятное выводит, а с математикой у меня проблемы

Comment: Тогда напишите в этом же вопросе, что выводит эта функция, что должна выводить, и спросите, почему так происходит.

Comment: что именно выводит Math.log() можно прочитать в документации. И все станет понятно.

Comment: На самом деле вопрос хороший, его только отформатировать надо. Насколько я понял, трудность в том, что Math.log вычисляет логарифм с основанием 10, а других оснований нет. Верно, @Ian Reed?

Comment: В школе советуют использовать формулу 7:  https://ege-resheniya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/log_formulas2.jpg

Comment: Вы знаете неправильно. Как и @Vestalt.

Comment: @Эникейщик, что именно неправильно?

Comment: Здесь есть ответ: https://www.techiedelight.com/ru/calculate-log-base-2-integer-java/ . Это вполне можно оформить как вопрос и ответ, как сделано на [английском Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831150/logarithm-algorithm).

Comment: @Vestalt ну посмотрите же в документацию

Comment: Увидел, спасибо. Основание `e`, а не 10.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно формуле (n - любое число):

```
log b (a) = log n (a) / log n (b)
```

Тогда вычисление логарифма с произвольным основанием в java будет выглядеть так:

```java
public class Logarithm {
    public static double log(int base, int x) {
        return Math.log(x) / Math.log(base);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Logarithm.log(2, 50));
    }
}
```

Вывод:

> 5.643856189774724